# What is the punishment for breaking an oath to Allah about playing games?

Tags: punishment, oaths, game

I promised to Allah that I will not play online games but I didn't keep my promise.

First question: what is the punishment?  Second question: what will the new punishment be if I still play?

Will the same punishment repeat until I leave my behavior?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you have to repent (at-tawba) from sin.

Second you should expiation vow with: 
  - Feed or clothe ten poor;
  - If you can't you should fast for three days.

For second question, if you don't make an oath you should just repent (at-tawba).

And if you end up back again, repent (at-tawba).

For more information, see the YouTube videos [What is the kaffara for a broken promise made to Allah](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UVkTnYAXZeM) by Sheikh Dr. Muhammad Salah, Learn Islam - Q&A, and [Repentance(Tawbah) By Mufti Menk](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PtynQ_TznW8).

Note: Vowing is not good in Islam just say "in·shal·lah" I won't do that, meaning if Allah wills it.